# Fazer upload de imagens por formulario php e exibir juntas numa imagem só

Tags: php, imagem, classes

estou tentando desenvolver um simples gerador de crachá que possa receber 3 imagens 1° fundo, 2° foto do funcionário, 3° logo da empresa dessa forma atualmente, e apresentar nome do funcionário e seu setor.
Atualmente consigo com algumas classes colocar nome do funcionário e setor para enviar via POST e exibir todos numa imagem só.

```html
<?php
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
//$fundo = $_POST['fundo'];

$imagem = ImageCreate(300,100);
$roxo = ImageColorAllocate($imagem, 150, 0, 50);
$branco = ImageColorAllocate($imagem, 255, 255, 255);
ImageString($imagem, 18, 10, 5, "$nome", $branco);
Imagejpeg($imagem);
ImageDestroy($imagem);

?>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Criador de Cracha</title>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="php.php">
   <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome Completo do Funcionario">
   <input type="text" name="nomeab" placeholder="Nome Abreviado">
   <input type="text" name="data" placeholder="Data de Admissão">
   <input type="text" name="setor" placeholder="Setor">
   <input type="text" name="cod" placeholder="Código Funcionario">
   <br>
   Selecione o fundo: <input name="file" type="file" />
   <br />
   Selecione png do funcionario: <input name="png" type="file" />
   <br />
   Selecione logo da empresa: <input name="png" type="file" />
   <br />
   <input type="submit" value="Gerar" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, mas qual é o problema?

Comment: Mostrar as imagens via POST e juntas numa só

Comment: [Edite seu post](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/197505/edit) e coloque qual o problema você esta tendo! por favor!

Comment: mostrar as imagens que selecionei no input type=file e juntas num jpg só

Comment: Como assim juntas? uma sobre a outra? ou uma do lado da outra?

Comment: Sim uma sobre a outra.

Comment: Tornando um arquivo só

Comment: *Atualmente consigo com algumas classes colocar nome do funcionário e setor para enviar via POST e exibir todos numa imagem só*. Você já está conseguindo fazer isso, pelo o que disse na pergunta. Pode reformulá-la melhor? Parece que ela está bem confusa.

Comment: Falei o que eu conseguia fazer que seria colocar textos na imagem via POST, $nome = $_POST... e para receber o arquivo $imagem = $_FILE, so que não consigo exibir a imagem que faço upload no html, só consigo mostrar o texto com string, está confusa pois não entendo do assunto e n sei explicar, mas praticamente o projeto é um gerador de cartão de membro isto é "cracha" só que sem usar BD